# Can't get SVN update to resolve conflict on Linux Server

Tags: apache, svn

I am using SVN update to update my web directory on my linux server.  when I do an sudo svn update it says theres a conflict.  i choose the accept theirs full option  which Im assuming it should pull the full repo file but it never seems to replace the file.  SVN reports update status G but the file remains the same.

what is going on,  how do i get the depot version.  This is on a server so there should never be a modified file or conflict to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

Revert all local modifications (and conflicts) after update:

`svn revert -R <path>`

Be careful, it wipe all your local changes

Answer (score 0):

It turns out what I was doing was correct, but their was an old cron job I wasn't aware of that was updating the file on the server outside of SVN.  So everytime I committed a change it was overwritten by a cron job kicking off an rsynch.